# Category term for "polite", and "offensive"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to complete the following sentence:

> It's not specifically polite, but it's not offensive either; it's **__** agnostic.

Is there a common category term for *polite*, *offensive*, *rude*, or *respectful*? I've tried to love *politeness*, or *courtesy*, but those don't seem to fit, to me.

I agree with many of the comments that *agnostic* is either a poor word choice, or at least overly restrictive.

Comment: A slightly different form may fit better, although it becomes quite a mouthful:  *courteousness*.

Comment: You can say "it's {courteousness / courtesy} agnostic". Either form is fine.

Comment: I don't really like this use of *agnostic*.  To me, agnosticism implies a choice and is used when expressing the idea that someone is of the belief that certain unknowns are unknowable. A person chooses to be agnostic, but things can't.  I prefer *neutral* here:  *it's courtesy neutral* not only because of the *choice* aspect but because what you're talking about is not unknown and unknowable.  I know others have latched onto the *X-agnostic* idiom and I don't expect that to change but thought it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any word that's a good fit in the sentence as shown; more possibilities may exist if *agnostic* is replaced by *neutral* or *free*.  However, consider the word *value*:

> It's not specifically polite, but it's not offensive either; it's value-agnostic.

Note, *value* is being used above to represent rules, principles, conventions and judgement regarding manners, etiquette, civility, politesse, habits and behavior, rather than in some other sense.

Two possible rewordings that avoid the need for a word as requested include the following:

> It's neither specifically polite, nor offensive either; it's neutral.
>   It's not specifically polite, nor offensive; it is amoral.

Comment: +1 for neutral. (Well, the whole answer is pretty good, but the very first thought I had was, "Why don't you just say 'neutral'?")

Answer (score 2):

How about [mores](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mores):

> A set of moral norms or customs derived from generally accepted
>   practices. Mores derive from the established practices of a society
>   rather than its written laws.

So you'd have: "It's not specifically polite, but it's not offensive either; it's mores-agnostic."

Comment: I feel even this one isn't *quite* right. But I seriously doubt there's anything better that's not at the very least *several* words.

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of *courtesy*, and so is *courtesy-agnostic* if you would.

Comment: As has probably been accepted by all now, *agnostic* is a poor starting-point. An alternative to *courtesy-neutral* would be *deference-neutral* - but it has the same problem in that we're just using the word for one end of the spectrum to denote the *entire* range of possibilities all the way through to *offensive*. I can't even think of an entire sentence that describes what exactly that "spectrum" actually *is*, though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that being polite is more or less the normal state of affairs, and being rude is conspicuous failure to be polite. The OP's proposed utterance is probably going to be awkward no matter what one chooses, just as the following would be a bit difficult to interpret:

> She's not pretty, and she's not plain; she's looks neutral.

On the other hand, try out the following, which picks out two adjectives occupying non-contiguous ends of the attractiveness continuum. (It sounds easier to interpret):

> She's not gorgeous, and she's not ugly; she's looks neutral.

To get what the OP wants, let's make a similar adjustment:

> It's not prim, and it's not offensive; it's politeness-neutral.